# .Net Standard project, How to use System.ServiceModel classes

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I have converted PCL project into .Net Standard 1.5 project. I have installed System.ServiceModel package from nuget. but cannot find way to use System.ServiceModel namespace.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why you have to use and where? because System.ServiceModel namespace is not compatible in .net 1.5 i am not sure but i hope

Comment: @Rajput I was calling WCF with custom behaviour

Comment: That's why serviceModel namespace is supported in .net 3.5 and onward

Comment: @Rajput, Issue resolved, when i installed System.ServiceModel.Security package. I got the System.ServiceModel namespace. It is a bug in VS.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Installing System.ServiceModel.Security package has resolved the issue.

After intalling above package. Now i can use System.ServiceModel namespace.

Also, i have to install System.ServiceModel.Http for proxies.

Comment: I am trying to use WSHttpBinding. I install the two packages above as well as System.ServiceModel.Web and it still does not recognize the object. Is this binding just not supported in .net standard?

Comment: @JonesCola, WSHttpBinding is supported in .Net Standard. This is something, i have achieved after a lot of hard work for both Json based csproj based .Net Standard project. Unfortunately, i don't remember the steps, It's been a long time. You should give it more tries. and also keep an eye open, someone can help here in community.