# Is Service Discovery available in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: wcf, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, service-discovery

Using the tip found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41421415), I've been able to include general WCF support while converting my .NET Framework 4.8 assembly to .NET Standard 2.0. However, my code relies heavily on Service Discovery.

In a brute-force approach I tried these packages:

```
System.ServiceModel.Duplex
System.ServiceModel.Federation
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.ServiceModel.NetTcp
System.ServiceModel.Primitives
System.ServiceModel.Security
System.ServiceModel.Syndication
```

...but none of them contain the supporting namespaces/classes.

Will it be possible to include Service Discovery support in my .NET Standard 2.0 assembly?

Comment: You can check out this link : [System.ServiceModel Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks, but that's the documentation for .NET Framework 4.8. I need packages for .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't read the last link clearly, this link is about Http and NetTcp[.NET Standard API Reference version 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0)

Comment: DiscoveryClient is [.net framework only](https://apisof.net/catalog/fb802a17-6c12-3dc1-5baa-c82fba7c3b5f) so you can't convert everything to .net standard.

Comment: Yes, I've just [discovered that](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4701). | @magicandre1981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly [DiscoveryClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.discovery.discoveryclient?view=netframework-4.8) is [.Net framework only](https://apisof.net/catalog/fb802a17-6c12-3dc1-5baa-c82fba7c3b5f)

[image]

so you can't convert everything to .net standard/.net core.